# Cascading select2 Combobox with Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, combobox

**Here's the code:** http://jsfiddle.net/W4qPT/

the combobox script is included *at the bottom*, if you remove it, everything works fine.

I cannot seem to get it to refresh the combobox with the new content given to me by the Knockout Ajax.

**HTML**

```
    <div>
        <div class="cbp-content" id="didScreen">
            <div>
                <table width='100%'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width='25%'>State</th>
                            <th width='25%'>City</th>
                            <th class='quantity' width='10%'>Quantity</th>
                            <th width='10%'></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <select class="combobox" data-bind="options: $parent.states, optionsText: 'name', value: state, optionsCaption: 'Select State'"></select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select class="combobox" data-bind="options: cities, optionsText: 'rc_abbr', optionsValue: 'id', value: city"></select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="quantity" data-bind="value: quantity" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn" data-bind="click: $parent.remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <button class="btn" data-bind="click: newItem">Add Item</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

---

**JavaScript (Knockout JS)**

```
var Item = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.state = ko.observable();
    self.city = ko.observable();
    self.quantity = ko.observable();


    self.cities = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.state.subscribe(function (state) {
        self.city("");
        self.cities.removeAll();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/json/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                json: ko.toJSON([{"id":"29","rc_abbr":"ANCHORAGE"}]),
            },
            success: function (response) {
                self.cities(response);
            }
        });
    });
};

var ViewModel = function (states) {
    var self = this;
    self.states = states;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([new Item()]);

    self.newItem = function () {
        self.items.push(new Item());
    };
    self.remove = function (item) {
        self.items.remove(item);
    };
};

var usStates = [{
    name: 'ALASKA',
    abbreviation: 'AK'
}];

window.vm = new ViewModel(usStates);
ko.applyBindings(window.vm, document.getElementById('didScreen'));
$(".combobox").select2();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `.select2()` again on all new comboboxes you create. You're now only calling it on comboboxes that exist when your DOM is ready.

You could change this:

```
self.newItem = function () {
    self.items.push(new Item());
};
```

To this:

```
self.newItem = function () {
    self.items.push(new Item());
    $(".combobox").not('.select2-container').select2();
};
```

Comment: Thank you for that input, the way the newItem works is it duplicates the cascading selects. So calling it again this way would mean they would have to hit 'add more' then put the city in. But the logic on this is good, I tried it like this: `$(".combobox").on("change", function(){
  $(".combobox").select2();
 });` however it still didn't work, any other recommendations?

Comment: I also tried placing your code in the ajax complete function, and it still didn't refresh the combobox.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I get exactly what you want to achieve, sorry.